# Problems with Nav

Tags: html, css

im hoping someone can help me with my navigation. For the time being i had the items in the nav as list items rather than wrapping them in a tags, but now i have wrapped them in a tags i have encountered problems which i have no idea how to fix or why its happening. Here is how the nav should look before the nav.

HTML

```
  <nav> <ul>
  <li>Home </li>
  <li> News </li>
  <li>Pre-Order </li> </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="news">

  <div class="ind"><article class="news"> <h4> Meet Elf At A Store Near You </h4><img class="story" src="year.jpg"/> <p class="story"> Want to meet buddy himself, 
  well now you can. He will be at numerous shopping centres all around the country to meet his fans.
  A list of destinations buddy will be attending will be released soon so you can have time to meet
  the Giant Elf. Feel free to have pictures with him and have a short chat, and dont be worried all elves are 
  friendly... well most!</p> </article></div>

  <div class="ind"><article class="news"> <h4> Elf Set To Be The Chrismas Movie Of The Year </h4> <img class="story" src="year2.jpg"/><p class="story"> With 
  plenty of other christmas movies due for release in december their is alot of competition for buddies
  charming story, but critics have already said Elf is due to be the success story this christmas.
  The Times said "The best christmas movie for many a year" while Total Film had already claimed it was
  a "modern day classic</p> </article></div>

  <div class="ind"><article class="news"> <h4> Pre-Order The DVD </h4> <img class="story" src="dvdnews.jpg"/><p class="story"> We can now announce that
  the DVD is avaible to order on our website. Follow the preorder link to get it delivered for our launch
  date. You can choose from the standard version and the special edition. We suggest you get the 
  special edition to make the most of the christmas feel and prolong Buddys Christmas spirit for
  as long possible.</p></article></div>

  <div class="ind"><article class="news"> <h4> Elf Set For Cinemas </h4> <img class="story" src="cinema.jpg"/><p class="story"> The Movie will now be in cinemas 
  earlier than expected. The date has moved forwards to 11th Decemeber after the incredible amound of interest.
  This will give everyone as much chance to watch it before christmas without the worry out it not being
  sold out. Be sure to book your tickets in advance to avoid dissapointment</p> </article>
  </div></div>


  <footer>
        <div id="social">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ElfMovie"><img class="socialpics" src="facebook.png"/> <a/>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/ElfMovieQuotes"><img class="socialpics2" src="newtwit.png"/> <a/>
        </div>
        <div id="bottomrow">
        <img id="firstfootpic" class="footpic" src="dvdlogo.gif"/>
        <img class="footpic" src="bluray.png"/>
        <img class="footpic" src="universallogo.png"/>
        <img class="footpic" src="cardslogo.png"/> </div>
  </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body { 
       margin:10px auto;
       width:70%;
       paddding:0px;
       max-width:1000px;
}

header {background-image:url("banner.png");
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       border-radius:20px;
       width;100%;
       height:200px;

        }

.title {
       height:180px;
       width:180px;
       margin-left:40%;
       margin-top:10px;}

.tagline {z-index:1;
         position:relative;
         bottom:95px;
         color:white;      
         font-weight:900;
         font-size:40px;
         text-align:center;
         color:black;
         font-family:Tw Cen MT;
         letter-spacing:5px; 
      }

.snow {
      width:100%;
      max-height:100px;
      z-index:-1;
      border-radius:20px; }

.cont {
         width:100%;
         height:560px;
         /*background-color:rgb(44,132,255);*/
         background:-moz-linear-gradient(rgb(36,124,250) 60%, white);
         border-radius:20px;
         position:relative;




         }

.pic {
       max-height:600px;
       max-width:900px;
       border-radius:30px;
       min-height:600px;
       min-width:900px; }



 article.drop {
         border-radius:30px;
         margin-bottom:20px;
}

nav {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-17px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:rgb(214,20,21);
    height:60px;
    border-radius:10px
}

nav ul li{
           float:left;
           padding:0px 95px;
           list-style:none;
           color:white;
           margin-top:13px;
           font-family:Tw Cen MT;
           font-weight:bold;
           font-size:2em;
           transition:color 0.5s linear 0s;
           text-decoration:none;
           list-style-type:none;
           }

nav ul li :nth-child(1) {
    border-right:1px solid white} 


nav ul li :nth-child(2) {
    border-right:1px solid white} 

nav ul li :hover {
    color:lightgreen;
  }

article.drop { 
        width:29%;
        height:325px;
        display:inline;
        float:left;
        padding:15px;
        color:transparent;
        font-family:Tw Cen MT;
        margin-left:8px;
        -moz-transition-duration:2s;
        max-height:500px;
        color:transparent;
        position:relative;
        z-index:100;




       }

.art1 {background-color:green;
       }       

.art2 {background-color:rgb(214,20,21);
       }

.art1, .art2 {
       margin-top:10px }


.pic1 {width:274px;
      height:246px;
      border-radius:10px;
      margin-top:-10px;
      border:2px solid white;
} 

.pic2 {width:274px;
      height:246px;
      border-radius:10px;
      margin-top:-10px;
      border:2px solid white;
 } 

.pic3 {width:274px;
      height:246px;
      border-radius:10px;
      margin-top:-10px;
      border:2px solid white;
}

.pic1:hover {
            transform:scale(1.025) }

.pic2:hover {
            transform:scale(1.025) }

.pic3:hover {
            transform:scale(1.025) }

h2 {
         padding:10px;
         margin-top:-10px;
         color:white;} 

article.drop:hover {

        height:500px; 
        width:29%;
        display:inline;
        float:left;
        padding:15px;
        color:white;
        font-family:Tw Cen MT;
        margin-left:8px;



        }

footer {
       background-color:rgb(36,124,250);
       height:250px;
       width:100%;
       float:clear; 
       border-radius:5px}

h3 {
   position:absolute;
   top:700px;

}

.footpic {
         float:left;
         width:100px;
         height:60px;
         padding:55px;
         margin-top:30px
         }

#firstfootpic {
              margin-left:40px; 
              }

aside.artbot {

             position:absolute;
             top:400px;
             left:0px; 

             }

p.artbot {
         color:blue;
         font-family:Tw Cen MT; 
         margin:0 auto;
         margin-left:10px;
         -moz-column-count:3;
         -moz-column-gap:70px;
         -moz-column-rule-width:10px;
         text-align:justify;
         margin-left:50px;
         width:90%;
         font-weight:500;
         text-transform:capitalize;
         }


.socialpics {
            width:80px;
            height:60px;
            margin-top:20px;
            margin-left:-15px;
             }

.socialpics2 {width:80px;
            height:70px;
            margin-top:20px;
            float:right
              }

.cb {
    height:80px;
    width:60px;
    position:absolute;
    top:400px;
    left:290px}

.cb2 {
    height:80px;
    width:60px;
    position:absolute;
    top:400px;
    left:600px}

    body {width:70%;
     font-family:Tw Cen MT}


div.news {
      background-color:rgb(214,20,21);
      /*background-image:url(wallpaper.jpg);*/
      width:100%;
      height:1200px;
      color:white;
      padding:30px;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      border-radius:10px;
      border:1px solid white
       }

article.news {           
             width:100%;
             height:260px;
             background-color:rgb(214,20,21);
             box-sizing:border-box;
             position:relative;
             top:-25px;
             border-radius:10px;
             opacity:0.85;
             ;
             }    

article.news:hover {           
             transform:scale(1.025);
             opacity:1;
             }    

h4 {
   color:white;
   width:100%;
   background-color:green;
   padding:10px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   border-radius:10px;
   text-align:center;



  }

p.story {
        width:50%;
        padding-left:40px;
        padding-top:10px;
        font-size:1.1em;
        margin-top:42px
 }

img.story {
          height:180px;
          width:300px;
          float:right;
          margin-right:40px;
          border-radius:5px;
          }

div.ind {
        margin-bottom:0px;}

footer {
       margin-top:0px }
```

Now this is with a tags around, they render differently.
1. They all appear on different lines.
2. Cant get rid on bullet points despite inputting "none"
3. 3 link have a border right, but it should just be the first two.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="order.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="news.css">
  </head>
  <body>
 <header> 
  </header>

  <nav> <ul>
  <li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="news.html"> News </a></li>
  <li> <a href="order.html"> Pre-Order </a></li> </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="news">

  <div class="ind"><article class="news"> <h4> Meet Elf At A Store Near You </h4><img class="story" src="year.jpg"/> <p class="story"> Want to meet buddy himself, 
  well now you can. He will be at numerous shopping centres all around the country to meet his fans.
  A list of destinations buddy will be attending will be released soon so you can have time to meet
  the Giant Elf. Feel free to have pictures with him and have a short chat, and dont be worried all elves are 
  friendly... well most!</p> </article></div>

  <div class="ind"><article class="news"> <h4> Elf Set To Be The Chrismas Movie Of The Year </h4> <img class="story" src="year2.jpg"/><p class="story"> With 
  plenty of other christmas movies due for release in december their is alot of competition for buddies
  charming story, but critics have already said Elf is due to be the success story this christmas.
  The Times said "The best christmas movie for many a year" while Total Film had already claimed it was
  a "modern day classic</p> </article></div>

  <div class="ind"><article class="news"> <h4> Pre-Order The DVD </h4> <img class="story" src="dvdnews.jpg"/><p class="story"> We can now announce that
  the DVD is avaible to order on our website. Follow the preorder link to get it delivered for our launch
  date. You can choose from the standard version and the special edition. We suggest you get the 
  special edition to make the most of the christmas feel and prolong Buddys Christmas spirit for
  as long possible.</p></article></div>

  <div class="ind"><article class="news"> <h4> Elf Set For Cinemas </h4> <img class="story" src="cinema.jpg"/><p class="story"> The Movie will now be in cinemas 
  earlier than expected. The date has moved forwards to 11th Decemeber after the incredible amound of interest.
  This will give everyone as much chance to watch it before christmas without the worry out it not being
  sold out. Be sure to book your tickets in advance to avoid dissapointment</p> </article>
  </div></div>


  <footer>
        <div id="social">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ElfMovie"><img class="socialpics" src="facebook.png"/> <a/>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/ElfMovieQuotes"><img class="socialpics2" src="newtwit.png"/> <a/>
        </div>
        <div id="bottomrow">
        <img id="firstfootpic" class="footpic" src="dvdlogo.gif"/>
        <img class="footpic" src="bluray.png"/>
        <img class="footpic" src="universallogo.png"/>
        <img class="footpic" src="cardslogo.png"/> </div>
  </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body { 
       margin:10px auto;
       width:70%;
       paddding:0px;
       max-width:1000px;
}

header {background-image:url("banner.png");
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       border-radius:20px;
       width;100%;
       height:200px;

        }

.title {
       height:180px;
       width:180px;
       margin-left:40%;
       margin-top:10px;}

.tagline {z-index:1;
         position:relative;
         bottom:95px;
         color:white;      
         font-weight:900;
         font-size:40px;
         text-align:center;
         color:black;
         font-family:Tw Cen MT;
         letter-spacing:5px; 
      }

.snow {
      width:100%;
      max-height:100px;
      z-index:-1;
      border-radius:20px; }

.cont {
         width:100%;
         height:560px;
         /*background-color:rgb(44,132,255);*/
         background:-moz-linear-gradient(rgb(36,124,250) 60%, white);
         border-radius:20px;
         position:relative;




         }

.pic {
       max-height:600px;
       max-width:900px;
       border-radius:30px;
       min-height:600px;
       min-width:900px; }



 article.drop {
         border-radius:30px;
         margin-bottom:20px;
}

nav {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-17px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:rgb(214,20,21);
    height:60px;
    border-radius:10px
}

nav ul li a{
           float:left;
           padding:0px 95px;
           list-style:none;
           color:white;
           margin-top:13px;
           font-family:Tw Cen MT;
           font-weight:bold;
           font-size:2em;
           transition:color 0.5s linear 0s;
           text-decoration:none;
           list-style-type:none;
           }

nav ul li a :nth-child(1) {
    border-right:1px solid white} 


nav ul li a:nth-child(2) {
    border-right:1px solid white} 

nav ul li a:hover {
    color:lightgreen;
  }

article.drop { 
        width:29%;
        height:325px;
        display:inline;
        float:left;
        padding:15px;
        color:transparent;
        font-family:Tw Cen MT;
        margin-left:8px;
        -moz-transition-duration:2s;
        max-height:500px;
        color:transparent;
        position:relative;
        z-index:100;




       }

.art1 {background-color:green;
       }       

.art2 {background-color:rgb(214,20,21);
       }

.art1, .art2 {
       margin-top:10px }


.pic1 {width:274px;
      height:246px;
      border-radius:10px;
      margin-top:-10px;
      border:2px solid white;
} 

.pic2 {width:274px;
      height:246px;
      border-radius:10px;
      margin-top:-10px;
      border:2px solid white;
 } 

.pic3 {width:274px;
      height:246px;
      border-radius:10px;
      margin-top:-10px;
      border:2px solid white;
}

.pic1:hover {
            transform:scale(1.025) }

.pic2:hover {
            transform:scale(1.025) }

.pic3:hover {
            transform:scale(1.025) }

h2 {
         padding:10px;
         margin-top:-10px;
         color:white;} 

article.drop:hover {

        height:500px; 
        width:29%;
        display:inline;
        float:left;
        padding:15px;
        color:white;
        font-family:Tw Cen MT;
        margin-left:8px;



        }

footer {
       background-color:rgb(36,124,250);
       height:250px;
       width:100%;
       float:clear; 
       border-radius:5px}

h3 {
   position:absolute;
   top:700px;

}

.footpic {
         float:left;
         width:100px;
         height:60px;
         padding:55px;
         margin-top:30px
         }

#firstfootpic {
              margin-left:40px; 
              }

aside.artbot {

             position:absolute;
             top:400px;
             left:0px; 

             }

p.artbot {
         color:blue;
         font-family:Tw Cen MT; 
         margin:0 auto;
         margin-left:10px;
         -moz-column-count:3;
         -moz-column-gap:70px;
         -moz-column-rule-width:10px;
         text-align:justify;
         margin-left:50px;
         width:90%;
         font-weight:500;
         text-transform:capitalize;
         }


.socialpics {
            width:80px;
            height:60px;
            margin-top:20px;
            margin-left:-15px;
             }

.socialpics2 {width:80px;
            height:70px;
            margin-top:20px;
            float:right
              }

.cb {
    height:80px;
    width:60px;
    position:absolute;
    top:400px;
    left:290px}

.cb2 {
    height:80px;
    width:60px;
    position:absolute;
    top:400px;
    left:600px}

    body {width:70%;
     font-family:Tw Cen MT}


div.news {
      background-color:rgb(214,20,21);
      /*background-image:url(wallpaper.jpg);*/
      width:100%;
      height:1200px;
      color:white;
      padding:30px;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      border-radius:10px;
      border:1px solid white
       }

article.news {           
             width:100%;
             height:260px;
             background-color:rgb(214,20,21);
             box-sizing:border-box;
             position:relative;
             top:-25px;
             border-radius:10px;
             opacity:0.85;
             ;
             }    

article.news:hover {           
             transform:scale(1.025);
             opacity:1;
             }    

h4 {
   color:white;
   width:100%;
   background-color:green;
   padding:10px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   border-radius:10px;
   text-align:center;



  }

p.story {
        width:50%;
        padding-left:40px;
        padding-top:10px;
        font-size:1.1em;
        margin-top:42px
 }

img.story {
          height:180px;
          width:300px;
          float:right;
          margin-right:40px;
          border-radius:5px;
          }

div.ind {
        margin-bottom:0px;}

footer {
       margin-top:0px }
```

Im sure its a very easily solution but at the moment i just cant see what i am doing wrong.

Comment: It would be easier, if you provided a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you simply appended `a` to your `li` selectors without anticipating that some of the specified styles should actually apply to the `li` itself, namely `float:left;`

Its hard to say resolutely without a demo, but the below may help:

```
nav ul li{ /* <--- you need to seperate out the styles which apply to the li specifically*/
      float:left;
      list-style:none;
      margin-top:13px;
}
nav ul li a{
      padding:0px 95px;
      display:block;
      color:white;
      font-family:Tw Cen MT;
      font-weight:bold;
      font-size:2em;
      transition:color 0.5s linear 0s;
      text-decoration:none;
}
nav ul li:nth-child(1) {
    border-right:1px solid white
} 


nav ul li:nth-child(2) {
    border-right:1px solid white
} 

nav ul li a:hover {
    color:lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: @user3885714 Just to add.. using `nth-child` like this can be troublesome, say when you have 8 or 10 list items. Better assign border to the `li` and set only `last-child`'s border-right as `none`.

Comment: and thanks IKmhr, thinking about it that would be a more efficient way of doing it